# Monitoring Windows Server 2016 Servers with SCOM 2012 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2016, scom, agent

I have an instance of **SCOM 2012 R2** running in a client environment. We are currently **monitoring 2008 R2 and 2012 R2 servers** with it. We had to migrate two of the 2012 servers to fresh instances of **server 2016**. The scom agent is running on both of these 2016 instances but nothing is returned in the monitoring - windows server state section about these new servers.

Is it ***possible to monitor servers running windows 2016 with SCOM 2012R2***? I don't have a lot of experience using SCOM so this is all kind of new to me. I'd appreciate any help/assistance.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the scenario you describe is possible.

It sounds like the when the agent was upgrade, the agent settings might have gotten lost.

On the server that isn't reporting in, open the Control Panel, look for the "Operations Manager Agent" applet, open it, and then verify if the information listed is correct.

When you inspect the settings, make sure the Management Group name is EXACTLY like it is in SCOM (it is case-sensitive).

If everything looks correct, in your SCOM console, go to the Administration pane and verify that the agent isn't sitting in "Administration\Device Management\Pending Management" waiting to be approved.

Comment: Appreciate the response. I ended up uninstalling and reinstalling shortly after I posted and was able to get the 2016 servers to communicate with my 2012 SCOM server.